# How to add audio to merged mp4 video(gif and image)?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, android, android-studio

I have created a mp4 video after merging gif file and image file and that duration is 10 seconds but should be 1 second.
Now i am adding the audio but it is only playing in 1 second part.
It should be be played in whole video.

`String[] complexCommand = {"-i", animated.gif, "-i", image.jpeg, "-filter_complex", "[0]scale=w=iw/1:h=ih/1[over];[1][over]overlay=" +
                "x=" +
                (x - imgWidth / 2) +
                ":" +
                "y=" +
                (y - imgHeight / 2)
                ,
                "-s", mWidth + ":" + mHeight, "-c:a", "copy", "-y", video.mp4};`

How to add the audio in the merged video with 1 seconds duration?

How to maintain the duration of merge video?

Comment: Show the actual ffmpeg command being executed by the script and provide the complete log from the command.

Comment: Actually i want to merge two video and both contains audio but after merging them second clip audio is mute.

Comment: Now i tried to get first video's audio and second video's audio and now merging both of them but first one is not audible.

 `ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -i 1.mp3  -filter_complex amerge -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 audiofinal.mp3`

Comment: This command is only MP3, but your question asks how to make MP4. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Actually i want to merge two video and both contains audio but after merging them second clip audio is mute.
That is why i asked the question.

Comment: Then show the actual command and the complete log as requested previously.

Comment: could you please tell me that why second video speed is increasing after merging two videos?

Comment: Impossible to provide answer without seeing your actual ffmpeg command and the complete log.